# JQuery dynamically prepopulate optgroup option

Tags: jquery, optgroup

By clicking on `promotion_image_category_ids` select i want each corresponding optgroup `subcategory_ids` to be selected

So far trying to get current option in select by iterating over each `#select` like this:

```
var selecting = $("#myhtml #selects")

selecting.find("#promotion_image_category_ids").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/697YK/1/)

Comment: You can select only 1 option on a select element. This question seems all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#selects select").change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

If you want the text, do:

```
var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

Inside the handler.

Comment: is it possible to find out selected option in scope of `#selects` ids, as you can see in jsfiddle i've more than one `#selects`

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique! Change your repeating ID's to a `class` and you'll be fine.